# Fecha actual por default en input con JS

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente codigo, donde por default le pongo una fecha estatica, pero quisiera que esta cambiara por la fecha actual, como puedo lograrlo?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#datepicker_from').val('07/16/2019');
    $('#datepicker_to').val('07/16/2019');

})
```

Comment: La fecha actual en que formato?

Comment: Como en la que se muestra en el val, del codigo

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? podrías compartirlo por favor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según entiendo defines el mismo valor de fecha en los 2 inputs `datepicker_from` y `datepicker_to`, podrías obtener la fecha con JS separando, dia, mes y año. Luego enviando el valor obtenido al val de jQuery, algo así:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

var fecha = new Date();

var mes = fecha.getMonth()+1;
var dia = fecha.getDate();
var anio = fecha.getFullYear();

var output =(mes<10 ? '0' : '') + mes + '/' +(dia<10 ? '0' : '') + dia+ '/'+anio;

$('#datepicker_from').val(output);
$('#datepicker_to').val(output);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="datepicker_from">
<input id="datepicker_to">
```